# UK visa with overstay background in Schengen

Tags: international-travel

I want to apply for a Schengen visa.

The problem is that last year I was working in Schengen zone. I resigned to find a new job. After six months the new employer told me my residence  had expired. I left quickly and voluntary.

Once I returned, I started applying and I was found a job in the Schengen zone. Now that I want to apply for the Schengen visa, its online form asks me declare my previous passport numbers and deliver copies of all pages to the visa officer, if I have any previous passports. 
How much would this cause problems for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never lie and always cooperate by giving all relevant documents and information (and an overstay is a relevant piece of information).

> I left Spain quickly and voluntary

What did the Spanish say when you left

- did they notice the overstay?

For important matters, information is exchanged between the countries.

Telling them the worst, discribing the situation as you have done here and let them deside how important it is, is better than them finding out later that you deliberately left out relevant information.

Comment: @MushaTanin Supply the Irish the copy that they requested. It is a Spanish affair, if they chose to do nothing, that is their affair. Mention it at any interview with the Irish and they probably won't care and note that your are honest about the error.

Comment: @MushaTanin yes, definitely and write a short letter about explaining the situation in Spain. Honesty is the best policy here.

Comment: @MushaTanin considering your position in Spain, had you simply renewed your residence permit at the time, other than a 'tsk, tsk, tsk' nothing probably would have happened. Accept this answer if you think the answer is correct for you (press the 0 betwwen the arrows next to the answer).

Comment: @MushaTanin a sound (at least in our language) expressing a slight disapproval because you did something wrong.

Comment: @MushaTanin I am surprised that the new university didn't assist you in this matter, this is something that they should have known about.

Comment: @MushaTanin You should intergrate all this information into the original question. All of thatshould be art of the accompanying letter for the visa application. I don't think this scenario will cause any problems.

Comment: The advice in the first line of this answer is quite appropriate. Even if you have not used your real name while posting here, you are still easily identifiable as there are not many PhD candidates from non-EU countries. You have to assume that immigration officials read this forum too.

Comment: Mark: Yes, I understand, last night I was so upset that I did it like this. I will follow your kind pieces of advice. Richard Thanks a lot. I am planning to give all what is necessary.